# Response Buffer Limit Exceeded error in ASP page

Tags: asp-classic, buffer

Error:
Response object error 'ASP 0251 : 80004005'

Response Buffer Limit Exceeded

Execution of the ASP page caused the Response Buffer to exceed its configured limit.

I use this code to solve this issue but problem is not solved

```
<% Response.Buffer=False %>
<%
do while not objrs.eof
response.flush
objrs.movenext
loop
%>
```

Plz, help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 5):

If setting `Response.Buffer` to false isn't helping then you are writing too much data via a single call to `Response.Write`.

Buffering is never really turned off. Each call to `Response.Write` will place the content written in ASP's buffer.  With `Response.Buffer = False` ASP will automatically flush the buffer after each call to `Response.Write`.

Therefore even with `Response.Buffer = False` it is still possible to get a "Buffer exceeded" error if the string passed to `Response.Write` would exceed the buffer size.

If you own the server then I would recommend leaving buffer on and instead increase the ASP "Response Buffering Limit" in IIS Manager.  OTH if you are using a hosting service then split up any large data being sent via `Response.Write` into smaller chunks say between 128KB to 1MB.

Comment: How to retrieve data from Database in small chunks in ASP?

Comment: Or split it in multiple `response.write` calls. If you are currently contencating and then writing a large string then try to use multiple `response.write` statements.

Comment: @Marv:  You are not really giving us enough info to help you.  Your last comment indicates that you may not of understood the help so far provided.  The code in your question doesn't make a great deal of sense either.  Please show a short example of what you are _really_ doing.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot combine `response.buffer = false` and `response.flush`. The use of `response.buffer = false` and `response.write` should work perfect.